# while function not executing under Else statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

```
 x=15
>>> if x==10:
    print ("not bad")
elif x==11:
    print ("good")
elif x==12:
    print ("best")
else:
    while x==30:
        x+=1
        print(x)
```

Comment: `while x==30` is never `True`.

Comment: Looks like a typo, maybe you wanted to write `while x<=30`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
x=15
>>> if x==10:
    print ("not bad")
elif x==11:
    print ("good")
elif x==12:
    print ("best")
else:
    while x < 30:
        x+=1
        print(x)
```